# Correct charset for |

Tags: java, android, string, text, character-encoding

I'm printing some text using a thermal printer. Everything works fine, except when I try to print the vertical bar character `|` my printer shows `Ö`, so I think that the error is in this part:

```
text=msg.getBytes("UTF8");
```

But I don't know why; if I'm using the UTF-8 charset, it seems like it should work. What's wrong?

I've tried it with ("UTF-8"), ("UTF8"), ("ISO8859-1"), ("ISO88591"), ("ISO-8859-1"), but the same thing happens with each.

**UPDATE**

This is what I like to print (In an Android device)
[image]

And this is what I'm getting ont he printer
[image]

Comment: Are you missing the dash? ...("UTF-8")

Comment: No, I've trying with ("UTF-8"),("UTF8"),("ISO8859-1"),("ISO88591"),("ISO-8859-1") and nothing... Still appears the 'Ö'

Comment: Maybe a language problem? On a QWERTZ keyboard (Germany) the ö could be where the pipe character is

Comment: Have you tried getBytes("ASCII")?

Comment: I updated my answer, so now you can see what I'm doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your thermal printer is configured to use one of the ancient character encodings where "uncommon" characters - brackets, braces, vertical bar, .... - are replaced by "national characters," for example ä, ö ü and ß in Germany. When the device is set to use these encodings there is no way to output the replaced characters.

Have a look at the user manual for the thermal printer. There must be a way to change the character mapping to standard ASCII. The Linux console for example has the escape code `"\033(B"` to return to the usual ASCII encoding.

Comment: Yeah, once apo time it works fine (about 2 months), but I don't remember what I changed, and just yesterday I realizad that issue...

Comment: I get the bytes of the message, and next rebuild a String from the byte[]... The string has the 3 |||, so, the problem isn't the charset. As you say, is the printer... I will continue checking that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, you had the reason, the problem is the charset of the printer, My printer has 14 internal character set, I had to choose the USA charset... This is the esc/pos command in decimal `{27,87,0}`